# QCTemplate compiled but can't link

Tags: c++, qt, linker-errors, google-ctemplate

I downloaded QCTemplate (http://code.google.com/p/qctemplate/).
There was a bug in version provided of CTemplate (0.95) so change
that version to CTemplate 2.2.

I compiled the library but when i try to run helloworld example i get 5
errors about ctemplate::TemplateCache  like:

```
qctemplate.lib(template.obj):-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "private: bool __thiscall ctemplate::TemplateCache::ExpandLocked(class ctemplate::TemplateString const &,enum ctemplate::Strip,class ctemplate::ExpandEmitter *,class ctemplate::TemplateDictionaryInterface const *,class ctemplate::PerExpandData *)" (?ExpandLocked@TemplateCache@ctemplate@@AAE_NABVTemplateString@2@W4Strip@2@PAVExpandEmitter@2@PBVTemplateDictionaryInterface@2@PAVPerExpandData@2@@Z) referenced in function "private: bool __thiscall ctemplate::TemplateTemplateNode::ExpandOnce(class ctemplate::ExpandEmitter *,class ctemplate::TemplateDictionaryInterface const &,char const * const,class ctemplate::PerExpandData *,class ctemplate::TemplateCache const *)const " (?ExpandOnce@TemplateTemplateNode@ctemplate@@ABE_NPAVExpandEmitter@2@ABVTemplateDictionaryInterface@2@QBDPAVPerExpandData@2@PBVTemplateCache@2@@Z)
```

How can i make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. I compiled the src of QCtemplate but somehow there was no template_cache.cc imported in Qt Creator and it was not compiled. I added it manualy and compiled again and it works now.